# how can i convert this number to arguments?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, bignumber

[image]

in this img you seen 570.1777 ext TRANSFER by function
i want now how can convert this amount to arguments easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"1ee8ce2ce2ba93bc60" in hexadecimal is 570177717225592700000 in decimal.

ETH has 18 "decimal places", so your number is 570177717225592700000 / 10^18.

In the `geth` console, you can type the following to get the number:

```
> new BigNumber("1ee8ce2ce2ba93bc60", 16)
570177717225592700000
```

And you can shift the "decimal places" 18 places using the following command in the `geth` console:

```
> new BigNumber("1ee8ce2ce2ba93bc60", 16).shift(-18)
570.1777172255927
```

To go the other way around, you can convert from the ETH number to the raw decimal number:

```
> web3.toWei(570.1777172255927, "ether")
"570177717225592700000"
```

And you can convert this to the hexadecimal number using:

```
> web3.toHex(web3.toWei(570.1777172255927, "ether"))
"0x1ee8ce2ce2ba93bc60"
```